# Mistake in contradiction argument to show that sheafification commutes with cokernel

Tags: category-theory, sheaf-theory, fake-proofs, abelian-categories

The sheafification functor is a left-adjoint to the forgetful functor. Hence it commutes with colimits. The cokernel is a colimit. Hence the cokernel of a sheafified morphism is the same as the sheafified cokernel. This is obviously false. Where was my mistake?

Comment: You neglected to mention what categories you are computing the colimits in. The _sheaf_ cokernel of the sheafified morphism is the same as the sheafified cokernel – that is true.

Comment: Okay, you're right! But how does one use an argument similar to mine to show that the *presheaf* kernel of a sheafified morphism is the same as the sheafified cokernel? Vakil alluded that this follows directly from the remark that sheafification is left-adjoint, but now that you pointed out that one has to be careful with the categories in which one takes the limit, I have no clue.

Comment: The presheaf kernel is the same as the sheaf kernel because the inclusion of sheaves into presheaves is a right adjoint and so preserves limits.

Comment: Aha! So what is *not* in general true is that the kernel of a sheafified morphism coincides with the sheafified kernel of the presheaf morphism (it does if the presheaf morphism was already a morphism of sheaves).

Comment: In fact, the (sheaf) kernel of the sheafification is the sheafification of the (presheaf) kernel – because sheafification is exact.